# javascript twitch api get status dosen't work

Tags: javascript, html

The request of twitch api dosen't work with m'y account

i try to use the friend account and her customer ID it works

```
function actuStream(){
    $.getJSON('https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/tiwabs&client_id=fgg8ys5fj5eg2founn7t77r3rby9vs', function (channel) {
        viewersNumber = document.getElementById('viewersnumber');
        viewers = document.getElementById('viewers');
        streamTitle = document.getElementById('streamtitle');
        if (channel['stream'] === null) {
            viewersNumber.innerHTML = '<span class="offline">HORS-LIGNE</span>';
            viewers.innerHTML = '';
            streamTitle.innerHTML = '';
        } else {
            viewersNumber.innerHTML = channel['stream']['viewers'];
            viewers.innerHTML = 'VIEWERS';
            streamTitle.innerHTML = '<p class="streamtitle"><span>&Eacute;MISSION:&nbsp;&nbsp;</span> ' + channel['stream']['channel']['status'] + '</p>';
        }
        /*
        $.getJSON(channel['stream']['channel']['_links']['subscribtions'], function(subs){
            alert(subs['_total']);
        });*/

    });
    if (count !== 0){
        if(min%3) ga('send', 'event', 'time', 'tracking', 'seconds', count);
        count += 60;
    }else{
        ga('send', 'event', 'time', 'tracking', 'seconds', count);
        count = 60;
    }
    min++;
}
```

```html
<div id="lefttheatre">
 <div class="toplive">
  <a id="theatre" onclick="theatre()" class="show-for-medium">Mode Th&eacute;&acirc;tre</a>
  <div class="viewersnumber" id="viewersnumber">
  </div>
  <div class="viewers" id="viewers">
  </div>
 </div>
 <div id="streamtitle"></div>
  <iframe id="stream" src="https://player.twitch.tv/?channel=tiwabs" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" height="100%" width="100%" allowfullscreen="true"></iframe>
 </div>
```

when i enter the link in google I get this error 
{"error":"Bad Request","status":400,"message":"The parameter \"id\" was malformed: the value must match the regular expression /^[0-9]+$/"}

I try with another account and client ID and its works perfectly

Comment: The ID for tiwabs is 168257684, not "tiwabs". Should be `https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/168257684?client_id=fgg8ys5fj5eg2founn7t77r3rby9vs`.

Comment: They dont display anything in m’y page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The regex is just for integers: https://regexr.com/4gglh

Your id is alphanumeric, and needs to be only numeric.

Also, refer to the new documentation: https://dev.twitch.tv/docs/api/ where your ID should be valid.